# Ruby on Rails app error in heroku deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

The application runs perfectly in development(local server) but not in production. 
I have the following in heroku logs(I have edited the logs to be easier to read, I just included what I think are the errors):

```
2015-05-15T23:58:43.894626+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (8.5ms)
2015-05-15T23:58:43.885011+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered movies/index.html.erb within layouts/application (17.5ms)
2015-05-15T23:58:43.896788+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `scard' for nil:NilClass):
2015-05-15T23:58:43.896785+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-05-15T23:58:43.896790+00:00 app[web.1]:     19:         <%if signed_in?%>
2015-05-15T23:58:43.896791+00:00 app[web.1]:     20:           <li>
2015-05-15T23:58:43.896794+00:00 app[web.1]:     22:               <i class="fi-shopping-cart"></i> My Cart (<span class="cart-count"><%=current_user.cart_count%></span>)
2015-05-15T23:58:43.896793+00:00 app[web.1]:     21:             <%= link_to cart_path do%>
2015-05-15T23:58:43.896796+00:00 app[web.1]:     23:             <%end%>
2015-05-15T23:58:43.896797+00:00 app[web.1]:     24:           </li>
2015-05-15T23:58:43.896799+00:00 app[web.1]:     25:           <li><%=link_to current_user.email, edit_user_registration_path%></li>
2015-05-15T23:58:43.896801+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/models/user.rb:36:in `cart_count'

2015-05-15T23:58:33.939033+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 3ms
2015-05-15T23:58:33.933343+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/movies/2" for 160.9.1.112 at 2015-05-15 23:58:33 +0000
2015-05-15T23:58:33.935944+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by MoviesController#show as HTML
2015-05-15T23:58:33.935966+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"id"=>"2"}
2015-05-15T23:58:33.938157+00:00 app[web.1]:   Movie Load (1.3ms)  SELECT  "movies".* FROM "movies" WHERE "movies"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
2015-05-15T23:58:33.939854+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-05-15T23:58:33.939856+00:00 app[web.1]: NoMethodError (undefined method `sismember' for nil:NilClass):
2015-05-15T23:58:33.939858+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/models/movie.rb:20:in `cart_action'
2015-05-15T23:58:33.939859+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/movies_controller.rb:9:in `show'

2015-05-15T23:58:28.575297+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/movies/1" for 160.9.1.112 at 2015-05-15 23:58:28 +0000
2015-05-15T23:58:28.581745+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"id"=>"1"}
2015-05-15T23:58:28.635038+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 53ms
2015-05-15T23:58:28.581412+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by MoviesController#show as HTML
2015-05-15T23:58:28.618562+00:00 app[web.1]:   Movie Load (1.6ms)  SELECT  "movies".* FROM "movies" WHERE "movies"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
2015-05-15T23:58:28.636023+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-05-15T23:58:28.636027+00:00 app[web.1]: NoMethodError (undefined method `sismember' for nil:NilClass):
2015-05-15T23:58:28.636029+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/models/movie.rb:20:in `cart_action'
2015-05-15T23:58:28.636031+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/movies_controller.rb:9:in `show'
```

***movie.rb:***

```
class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :purchases
  has_many :buyers, through: :purchases

  before_save :embed_video_url

  def poster
    "http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/#{poster_url}"
  end

  def imdb
    "http://www.imdb.com/title/#{imdb_id}/"
  end

  def embed_video_url
    self.video_url = "//www.youtube.com/embed/#{video_url.split('v=')[1].split('&list')[0]}"
  end

  def cart_action(current_user_id)
    if $redis.sismember "cart#{current_user_id}", id
      "Remove from"
    else
      "Add to"
    end
  end
end
```

I followed the official guide from heroku "https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/redistogo"
Even the test run ok but cant run in production
I know it's exhausting to check all these line so I will appreciate any help 
PS: In development/local server run perfect

Comment: please provide us with your `movie.rb` model as well as your movies controller

Comment: have you added something to provide redis on heroku( redis to go / redis cloud / ?? )   it isn't enabled by default

Comment: i have redis.rb with these lines:
uri = URI.parse(ENV["REDISTOGO_URL"])
REDIS = Redis.new(:url => uri)

I also tried to modify the code but didnt worked.I followed the officiall redis on heroku setup

Answer (score 0):

The error is appearing in the logs. See carefully.

```
NoMethod Error (undefined method sismember' for nil:NilClass): 2015-05 15T20:59:10.873219+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/models/movie.rb:20:incart_action'
```

Comment: you've only isolated the error but didn't give any solution to the problem

Comment: yes probably the redis isn't deployed on heroku. I tried to fix it but nothing